# How to accent insensitive fulltext search in Containstable on MS SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, containstable

I'm trying to update stored procedure to be able compare data accent insensitive. Current stored procedure use Containstable for fulltext search, but comparison is accent sensitive. Is there any chance to set collation (e.g. Latin1_General_CI_AI) for containstable?

Collation of db is accent sensitive.

I'm using MS SQL server 2012 Express.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the accent sensitivity of the full text catalog:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG [MyFullTextCatalog] REBUILD WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF
```

However, note that this is a global change, not only for this particular store procedure.

Comment: Thank you for answer, that is exactly what I need. This fulltext catalog is used only in this SP so it is not problem that it's global change.